# Prove that for $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x^5\sin^2(x))}$, its integral taken from $0$ to infinity is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Prove that for $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x^5\sin^2(x))}$, its integral taken from $0$ to infinity is bounded.

I tried finding an upper bound $g(x)$ for $f(x)$ so that integral of $g(x)$ eventually converges to some numerical value. But I could not find such a $g(x)$.

Comment: This seems like a tall order, especially given that the subsequence $f(\pi n) = \pi n$ goes to infinity

Comment: What is a tall order?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tall%20order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A_k=(k+1/2)\pi$. We have
$$\int_{A_k}^{A_{k+1}}f(x)dx<\int_{A_k}^{A_{k+1}}\frac{A_{k+1}}{1+A_k^5\sin^2(x)}dx=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{A_{k+1}}{1+A_k^5\sin^2(x)}dx<\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{A_{k+1}}{1+A_k^5 \left( \frac{x}{2}\right)^2}  dx<2\pi\frac{A_{k+1}}{A_k^{5/2}}$$
where in the last inequality we've used that $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. Summing over $k$ yields the result.

Comment: $\sin^2 x$ has zeroes at every multiple of $\pi$... what trivial estimate are you referring to?

Comment: @Zarrax what I've meant was compute $\int\frac{A_{k+1}}{1+A_k^5\sin^2(x)}dx$ and then make a trivial estimate to arrive at the last inequality. I edited my answer for hopefully more clarity, lmk if it is clear now.

Comment: Is that integral just $\pi A_{k+1}(1 + A_k^5)^{-{1 \over 2}}$? It's not the most well-known integral.

Comment: @Zarrax It might not be that well known. The $\pi$ comes from estimating $\arctan$ which pops up in the antiderivative. One could also use $\sin^2 x\geq\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2$ for the range considered and have a rational function to integrate if one doesn't like the other integral mentioned.

Comment: How did you know that the series so created is convergent?

Comment: @Eraserhead The sum is essentially $\sum n^{-3/2}$ which converges for example by comparing it with $\int x^{-3/2}dx$.

Comment: Ok. I got it.+1:)

Comment: @eulersgroupie I think using the lower bound $\sin^2 x \geq (x/2)^2$ is the way to go here... the resulting integral is familiar to most people.